# How to set MaxDate and MinDate of a SelectDateWidget in Django?

Tags: django, date, django-forms, django-widget

How to set MaxDate and MinDate of a SelectDateWidget in Django?

I am using that widget for a birthdate field.

```
#found in:
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
from django import forms

def someform(forms.Form):
    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget())
```

So how do I change its MaxDate and MinDate?
its default MinDate is this year and its MaxDate is 9 years after this year.

I want the MinDate to be maybe 100 years before this year and the Maxdate is 10 years before this year.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the years= argument:

```
def someform(forms.Form):
    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1990,2011))
```